# list of dict as json data read and convert to csv

Tags: python, json

I have a file with json data in the form of list of dicts as follows:

```
{"data":"value1","version":"value2","version1":"value3"}
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3"}
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3","hi":{"a":"true,"b":"false"}}
```

I am trying below code:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('test_json') as json_file:
 for data in json_file:
  json=json_normalize(json_file)
  json.to_csv('data.csv',index=false)
```

This is throwing an error as the input file as different keys in different rows, suppose a key is not present it has to fill null or leave it as blank. How to achieve this?

Comment: This is NOT list of dicts or array of json objects. It looks like ndjson/jsonlines.

Comment: You're not using your loop.  You want `json_normalize(data)` to get one line at a time.  Of course, that means you'll overwrite the file at every step.  I don't believe you will be able to use panda's cute methods here.  Just do it by hand -- it's not hard.

Comment: And you either need to write each row to a different CSV file, or use `mode="a"` to append each row to the file. Otherwise you're overwriting the file each time through the loop.